# How do we manage SMS and which is the best language to approach?

Tags: java, php, android, delphi, sms

I know that many has been ask for how to create a SMS server, but there has been been a fragmentation of knowledge because some just ask for a C# or PHP solution. My situation is different:

**I need to develop 2 different services:**

1. Receive SMS with a key work of what kind of information the client's client wants, like "FOOTBALL SCHEDULE" and the search in some data-base to send back to the sender's phone something like "12/12 NY X LA at 14:00h \n 13/12 DC X TX at 21:00h";
2. Client comes to my site and pays for 1000 SMS with message "Merry Christmas to you Girls!" with the possibility to enter the numbers or pick a random set in our own database according to what kind of people he/she wants to inform.

**For that I can use:**

1. Delphi *or* Java for Desktop/Web *or* Java for Android *or* PHP for Web;
2. MySQL *or* Firebird
3. A personal server *or* a Internet 3rd party server;
4. A SMS API service on the Internet *or* a personal phone with unlimited SMS sending pack.

So, the options are many. I can use a Android App in a Cell Phone or other kind of App in my PC connected to the Phone via USB. I can also use the Nokia NetBook that comes with a 3G slot and manage it from my App.

I have never made a program to handle any cell phone network services.

**What I'd like to know from the unlimited StackOverflow users wisdom is:**

1. Which of these options are the best to practice in the matter of available resources for SMS in these technologies?
2. Is there any finished community project with these arguments that I can be part of or import any piece of code/knowledge to mine?
3. Is there an API with these two services already available?

I am trying to avoid to contract a cellphone network provider to do that services. The cost would made it impossible. We are not intend to get a great profit, just to make these kind of services available in my region.

Thank You All!

Comment: I am studying `http://smsified.com/` and `http://nexmo.com/` to check if they can help me with this project.

Comment: well the first thing that comes to my mind is pricing. It really depends what market you need to cover, is it a global or a local market? If global go the api route, if local you can take things into your own hands with sms modems. Don't forget that most "unlimited" sms packs are in fact volume limited (ie max x sms per day sent).

Comment: this is very important really. It will cover just my city, but if some clients from other places visits the website, it's OK too! :)

Comment: I use Twilio to send SMS messages from my program. They have a good API and you can set up a free account to use a sandbox number while testing. You may be able to use it for what you need: http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: This twilio.com does not work for Brazil phone numbers :(

Comment: Brazil is listed as supported, see here: https://www.twilio.com/pricing/international-calling-rates

Comment: When they asked for a phone number for trial, my number was taken as invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are plenty of web to sms gateways available worldwide.

usually they offer a http interface for incoming and outgoing sms.

so the simplest solution would be to find an affordable gateway provider and setup any kind of webserver to listen to the http request from the gateway provider on incoming messages.
this could be done in any environment you're familiar with.

for outgoing messages you would simply call an url of the gateway provider like
    http://examplegateway.com/send?msisdn=23443&message=Merry+Christmas+to+you+Girls&secret=somesecrethash

this is easier than to program on the phone directly and usually cheeper, too. at least here in europe.

the contracts to the gateway providers come in as many differenty flavors as there are providers out there. with prepaid, postpaid, bulk-prices, monthly fee, pay-as-you-go you name it.

Comment: for inbound messages you need to rent a phonenumber from this gateway providers. so you need to find a provider who covers your country and to give you a local mobile number. this usually comes with a monthly fee.

but you could split the tasks of sending and receiving, depending on the price tags of the different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

1 ) IMHO, and for my experience, the option 4 is the best, because this option allows you to have better scalability, and you separate the SMS logic, from you inner logic. Also, you don't need a person for maintain any server.

In the future, maybe you need to create another service, or another app. Using the option 4, you can reuse some code (or only the SMS API). Now you're using Android, but in the future, maybe you wanna create a Java Desktop Client, or iOS, or windows mobile, or.....

2 ) IDK :(...

3 ) IDK 2. I'm from Argentina, and we use a service only available here (Intertron)